# get function returns invalid value

Tags: c++, getline

I'm working on a code for a school project which I can't use strings.
I'm having problems getting the value for hourlyPay.
The program's output:
5   Christine Kim         4.94066e-324
Although, the file contains the following:
5 Christine Kim       30.00

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

//Class decleration
class Employee 
{
  private:
    int id;            //Employee ID.
    char name[21];        //Employee name.
    double hourlyPay;   //Pay per hour.

  public:
    Employee(int initId=0, char [] =0, double initHourlyPay=0.0);  //Constructor.

    bool set(int newId, char [], double newHourlyPay);
    int getId() { return id; }
    const char * getName() { return name;}
    double getHourlyPay() { return hourlyPay;}


};

Employee::Employee( int initId, char initName[], double initHourlyPay)
{
  bool status = set( initId, initName, initHourlyPay);

  if ( !status )
  {
    id = 0;
    strcpy(name, "");
    hourlyPay = 0.0;
  }
}

bool Employee::set( int newId, char newName[], double newHourlyPay)
{
  bool status = false;

  if ( newId > 0)
  {
    status = true;
    id = newId;
    strcpy(name, newName);
    hourlyPay = newHourlyPay;
  }
  return status;
}

const int MAX_SIZE = 100;


int main()
{

    int id;             //Employee ID.
    char newName[21];

    double hourlyPay;   //Pay per hour.


    Employee list[15];  //Array to store


    ifstream masterFile;        //Opens master file.

    masterFile.open("master10.txt");

    int count = 0;
    if (masterFile)
    {
        for (count; count < 2; count++)
        {
            masterFile >> id;
            masterFile.ignore();
            masterFile.getline(newName, 21);
            masterFile >> hourlyPay;
            list[count].set(id, newName, hourlyPay);
        }
    }

    masterFile.close(); //Close master file.

    cout << list[0].getId() << "   " << list[0].getName() << "  " << list[0].getHourlyPay();
}
```

The original file contains more lines, but I narrowed it down in order to figure out my error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Forcing people to use C style strings instead of C++ strings is a clear sign of very common bad C++ teaching. Consider getting a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9254539).

Comment: `hourlyPay` has been read when maststerFile.getline(...), it's in the `newName`

Comment: Unlike `>>` which will stop at whitespace, `getline` will read until the end of the file, the delimiter (default is `'\n'`, aka the end of the line), or the C string that the extracted input will be stored in is full. None of these will stop the function from reading the hourly pay when it reads in the name.

Comment: Using *double* for currency is not a good idea (people get really upset when you start losing money because values cannot be exactly represented in floating-point notation). Best use a signed (or unsigned) integer of sufficient size to hold the value (multiplied by `100`) so that every value can be represented exactly. See, e.g. [How to read and store currency values in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979478/how-to-read-and-store-currency-values-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

//Class decleration
class Employee 
{
  private:
    int id;            //Employee ID.
    char name[21];        //Employee name.
    double hourlyPay;   //Pay per hour.

  public:
    Employee(int initId=0, char [] =0, double initHourlyPay=0.0);  //Constructor.

    bool set(int newId, char [], double newHourlyPay);
    int getId() { return id; }
    const char * getName() { return name;}
    double getHourlyPay() { return hourlyPay;}


};

Employee::Employee( int initId, char initName[], double initHourlyPay)
{
  bool status = set( initId, initName, initHourlyPay);

  if ( !status )
  {
    id = 0;
    strcpy(name, "");
    hourlyPay = 0.0;
  }
}

bool Employee::set( int newId, char newName[], double newHourlyPay)
{
  bool status = false;

  if ( newId > 0)
  {
    status = true;
    id = newId;
    strcpy(name, newName);
    hourlyPay = newHourlyPay;
  }
  return status;
}

const int MAX_SIZE = 100;


int main()
{

    int id;             //Employee ID.
    char newName[21];

    double hourlyPay;   //Pay per hour.


    Employee list[15];  //Array to store


    ifstream masterFile;        //Opens master file.

    masterFile.open("master10.txt");

    int count = 0;
    if (masterFile)
    {
        for (count; count < 2; count++)
        {
            masterFile >> id;
            masterFile.ignore();
            masterFile.get(newName, 21);
            masterFile >> hourlyPay;
            list[count].set(id, newName, hourlyPay);


        }

    }

    masterFile.close(); //Close master file.

    cout << list[0].getId() << "   " << list[0].getName() << "  " << list[0].getHourlyPay();
}
```

I only changed getline to get and now it can read in the middle of a line with a limit of 20 chars.
I appreciate everyone's attention and help.

Comment: If you are guaranteed that the name is `20` char of less, **and** it is contained in a *fixed-length* field, your code makes sense -- but names rarely are limited to `20` characters, and as written, if name is `Ho Wu` you  are either storing a whole lot of spaces, or you just included `hourlyPay` as part of the name. You can't "*guess*" parsing data. If you are guaranteed the fixed-length field in the data file, you are OK. Otherwise, you will need a bit more detail in your parse. (and what if there is more than `1-char` between `id` and `name`?

Comment: I appreciate your comments. I should have added more comments from the original assignment. One of the original requirements: "You can also assume that the name occupies 20 columns in the file".

Comment: Oh well -- there is a lot of good learning in the manual parse I provided. Keep it in your hip-pocket for the time when you no longer have such a guarantee `:)`

Comment: I most certainly will. Your comment make a lot of sense, I just think the code you provided is a bit too complicated for me (as I mentioned earlier I'm a beginner). With that being said, I'd prefer to write a code I truly understand, rather than just copy paste.

Comment: Yes, as I was going though it, I was either really impressed with your professor making you learn manual parsing -- or I had the suspicion that it may be more than you were asking for. Either way. All it does is read the whole line into an array, and then move a couple of pointers forwards and backwards to bracket the fields you need (and most of it is just validation of each step -- which is as important as the steps themselves). Good luck with your coding.

Comment: As an amazing exercise in pointers, you can simply take a piece of graph-paper and write the characters in the line out in the squares as they are in the file, and then take a pencil and just follow the pointer assignments and movements, labeling where each is pointing as you work through the loop -- to see exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to contain a name with blank space in the line, if you insist to do this, I think we can read the line and split the name and the hourlyPlay. The better way is that not contain blank space in the name, but use character like `_`, and replace the character with blank space after reading, the you can simple use `>>` to read each field

I modified a little to support multiline reading & printing, check the source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//Class decleration
class Employee
{
private:
    int id;            //Employee ID.
    char name[21];        //Employee name.
    double hourlyPay;   //Pay per hour.

public:
    Employee(int initId = 0, const char* = 0, double initHourlyPay = 0.0);  //Constructor.

    bool set(int newId, const char*, double newHourlyPay);
    int getId() { return id; }
    const char * getName() { return name; }
    double getHourlyPay() { return hourlyPay; }


};

Employee::Employee(int initId, const char* initName, double initHourlyPay)
{
    bool status = set(initId, initName, initHourlyPay);

    if (!status)
    {
        id = 0;
        strcpy(name, "");
        hourlyPay = 0.0;
    }
}

bool Employee::set(int newId, const char* newName, double newHourlyPay)
{
    bool status = false;

    if (newId > 0)
    {
        status = true;
        id = newId;
        strcpy(name, newName);
        hourlyPay = newHourlyPay;
    }
    return status;
}

int main()
{
    int id;                 //Employee ID.
    double hourlyPay;       //Pay per hour.
    vector<Employee> list;  //Array to store
    ifstream masterFile;    //Opens master file.
    char line[256];

    masterFile.open("master10.txt");
    if (masterFile)
    {
        while (!masterFile.eof())
        {
            masterFile >> id;
            masterFile.getline(line, sizeof(line));
            char* last_word = strrchr(line, ' ');
            line[last_word - line] = 0;
            hourlyPay = atof(last_word + 1);
            list.push_back(Employee(id, line, hourlyPay));
        }
    }

    //Close master file.
    masterFile.close();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
        cout << list[i].getId() << "   " << list[i].getName() << "  " << list[i].getHourlyPay() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Enable warnings - `for (count; count < 2; count++)` (`count` statement without effect `-Wunused-value`), either `for (; count < 2; count++)` or `for (count = 0; count < 2; count++)`  (just a nit -- but a really good idea...)

Comment: I can't use strings, only char arrays. The file is given and contains 15 lines. Each line contains the following:   (int) ID number.  
(char array)name of up to 20 characters.  
(double)pay rate per hour.  I narrowed it to one line in order to solve it quicker.

Comment: @ShaunPeretz I have edited my answer, removed the string, just use char array

Answer (score 0):

Data from the file is not correctly entered into the variables in your code. Here's a solution which is self explainatory.

```
for (count; count < 1; count++)
{
    char secondname[11];
    masterFile >> id;
    masterFile.ignore();
    masterFile >> newName;
    masterFile >> secondname;
    masterFile >> hourlyPay;

    strcat(newName, " ");
    strcat(newName, secondname);

    list[count].set(id, newName, hourlyPay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So.. you really want to do this with a plain old array of `Employee` and plain old character arrays and `cstring`?

There is absolutely nothing wrong with doing it that way -- and it will sure make you appreciate the convenience of using `string` and `vector`. But, that said, there is a wealth of valuable learning that can be gained from walking a pointer (or couple of pointers) through each line of data to parse the `id, name & hourlyPay` from each line of data.

The fly-in-the-ointment of the entire parsing process is not knowing how many `spaces` may be contained in `name` (it could have none, one, two, three, ...). Though, things are not as dire as they may appear. You know you have an `int` that begins the line of data and a `double` at the end -- everything left in between the whitespace after the `int` and before the `double` is your `name`.

The key here is really to read each line of data into a buffer (character array) as a `cstring`. Then you can use the standard tool `strtol` to read the `id` and advance a pointer to 1-past the last digit in `id`. You can then simply iterate forward on a character-by-character basis checking `if (isspace(*p))` and continuing to advance until a non-whitespace character is found (or you hit the *nul-terminating* character at the end). Once you find your non-whitespace character -- you have a pointer set to the beginning of `name`.

Now you have to work on the other end and *back up* until you find the `space` before `hourlyPay`. Not that difficult. You will need `strlen (buf)`, but at least using `masterFile.getline(..)` you are saved the need of trimming the `'\n'` from the end of the buffer by overwriting with a *nul-terminating* character. Simply set your end-pointer to `buf + len - 1` and you are sitting on the last digit of `hourlyPay`. Then in similar manner, it is just a matter up backing up `while (ep > sp && !isspace (*p))`  (you know if your end-pointer ever reaches your start-pointer sitting at the beginning of `name` the parse has failed)

Now remember, here you are 1-character **before** the beginning of `hourlyPay`, so when you go to convert `hourlyPay` using `strtod`, you must remember to use `p + 1` as the start of the cstring-segment for converting `hourlyPay`. As with any `strtoX` conversion, you have two primary tests (1) that following the conversion the start-pointer is not equal to the `endptr` parameter indicating that digits were actually converted to a number and (2) `errno` was not set during conversion -- indicating a failure in the actual conversion. (and when converting to a smaller type than the conversion -- e.g. to `int` using `strtol` -- you must check that the value converted is within the range of `int` before assigning to your value.

Now you have your `id` and `hourlyPay` -- all that is left is *backing up* from the beginning of `hourlyPay` to the end of `name`. You do this in like manner checking `isspace()` until it is no longer true, and that your pointer to the end of `name` is still greater than your pointer to the start of `name`. Now you can use `strncpy` to copy the `name` to your variable for `newName` by copying `p - sp + 1` characters (remember you are sitting on the last character with `p` so you will need to add `1` to get all characters in name.

Putting it altogether and providing comments inline below, you could do something like the following (noting that your original `class` and member functions were left unchanged -- only the parse of the `id, name & hourlyPay` in `main()` was dramatically affected) As always -- the key is to **validate each step** -- then you can have confidence in the data you are processing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <limits>

#define MAXLIST 16      /* if you need constants, define one (or more) */
#define MAXNM   64
#define MAXBUF  1024
#define FNAME   "dat/master10.txt"

using namespace std;

//Class decleration
class Employee 
{
  private:
    int id;                 //Employee ID.
    char name[MAXNM];       //Employee name.
    double hourlyPay;       //Pay per hour.

  public:
    Employee (int initId=0, char [] =0, double initHourlyPay=0.0);
    bool set (int newId, char [], double newHourlyPay);
    int getId() { return id; }
    const char *getName() { return name;}
    double getHourlyPay() { return hourlyPay;}
};

Employee::Employee (int initId, char initName[], double initHourlyPay)
{
  bool status = set(initId, initName, initHourlyPay);

  if (!status)
  {
    id = 0;
    strcpy(name, "");
    hourlyPay = 0.0;
  }
}

bool Employee::set (int newId, char newName[], double newHourlyPay)
{
    bool status = false;

    if (newId > 0) {
        status = true;
        id = newId;
        strcpy(name, newName);
        hourlyPay = newHourlyPay;
    }

    return status;
}

int main (void) {

    int id,                         //Employee ID.
        count = 0;
    long tmp;                       /* tmp for strtol conversion */
    char newName[MAXNM] = "",
        buf[MAXBUF] = "";           /* line buffer */
    double hourlyPay;               //Pay per hour.

    Employee list[MAXLIST];         //Array to store

    ifstream masterFile (FNAME);    //Opens master file.
    if (!masterFile.is_open()) {    /* validate file open for reading */
        cerr << "error: file open failed '" << FNAME << "'\n";
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line in masterFile into buf */
    while (count < MAXLIST && masterFile.getline (buf, sizeof buf)) 
    {
        size_t len = strlen (buf);  /* get length */

        char *sp = buf,             /* start pointer */
            *p = buf + len - 1,     /* working pointer */
            *ep = NULL;             /* end pointer for strtod conversion */

        /* parse and convert id, leaving sp 1-past last digit */
        errno = 0;                  /* zero errno before strtol conversion */
        tmp = strtol (buf, &sp, 0); /* store conversion in tmp */
        if (buf == sp) {            /* validate characters were converted */
            cerr << "error: no digits converted in id.\n";
            return 1;
        }
        if (errno != 0) {   /* validation errno not set */
            cerr << "error: failed converstion for id.\n";
            return 1;
        }
        /* validate tmp within range of integer */
        if (tmp < numeric_limits<int>::min() || 
            numeric_limits<int>::max() < tmp) {
            cerr << "error: id not within integer range.\n";
            return 1;
        }
        id = (int)tmp;  /* assign tmp to id */

        /* advance sp to 1st char in name */
        while (*sp && isspace (*sp))
            sp++;

        /* parse hourlyPay */

        /* work backward with p until space before hourlyPay found
         * always validate p > sp so you don't back up beyond the start of 
         * name (or the beginning of buf).
         */
        while (p > sp && !isspace (*p))
            p--;
        if (p > sp && !isdigit(*(p + 1))) { /* validate next char is digit */
            cerr << "error: failed to parse hourlyPay.\n";
            return 1;
        }

        errno = 0;                  /* zero errno before strtol conversion */
        hourlyPay = strtod (p+1, &ep);  /* convert hourlyPay to double */
        if (p + 1 == ep) {          /* validate characters were converted */
            cerr << "error: no digits converted in hourlyPay.\n";
            return 1;
        }
        if (errno != 0) {   /* validation errno not set */
            cerr << "error: failed converstion for hourlyPay.\n";
            return 1;
        }

        /* continue working backwards to end of name */
        while (p > sp && isspace (*p))
            p--;

        if (p <= sp) {  /* validate chars between sp & p */
            cerr << "error: failed to find end of name.\n";
            return 1;
        }

        len = p - sp + 1;       /* get number of chars in name */
        if (len > MAXNM - 1) {  /* validate it will fit in newName */
            cerr << "error: name exceeds" << len << "characters.\n";
            return 1;
        }
        strncpy (newName, sp, len); /* copy name to newName */

        /* set values in list[count], on success, increment count */
        if (list[count].set (id, newName, hourlyPay))
            count++;
    }
    masterFile.close();     //Close master file.

    /* outoput all employee id and hourlyPay information */
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        cout << list[i].getId() << "   " << list[i].getName() << 
                "  " << list[i].getHourlyPay() << '\n';
}
```

(now you see why `string` and the other C++ tools make things much nicer?)

**Example Input File**

The only data you posted was used as the input file, e.g.

```
$ cat dat/master10.txt
5 Christine Kim 30.00
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/employeepay
5   Christine Kim  30
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.